# Path/shape (not really sure how to formulate this question)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I would like delete parts of the shape with the path. 
Its 4am, and I have deadline to meet, and I am really stuck.

I am adding a picture so you can understand what i am jibbering about.

I would like the result to be like it is in the top picture, so it works on any color background, not only white (or background with same color as path)

(Top pic = Result I want to achieve) 
(Bot Pic = Where I am now)

.[image]

Comment: What have you tried to do? The pen tool is pretty good for these sorts of things though.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the stroke, go to Pathfinder, use the Divide command, delete the white object that was the stroke. Boom.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example for Adobe Illustrator, the home take message is that you should save your work in any editor as PNG file or any format that preserve transparency.

First of all you create one basic form without stroke and with any fill color you want -

[image]

[image]

and rotate-copy it 12 times for 30 degrees -

[image]

now I invoked Export function and saved it as png file with transparent background -  it will be visible proprietary on any background you want:

[image]